# Pass through GraphQL variables to second function in an elegant manner

Tags: graphql

I'm working with GraphQL and having some trouble finding the best way to pipe variables from the query to the result.

I have a schema like so:

```
type Fragment {

# The id of the fragment

  id: String!

# The key of the fragment
  key: String!

# The type of component
  component_type: String!

# The params used to build the fragment
  params: JSON

# Component data
  data: JSON

  children: [JSON]

  items: [JSON]


}
```

The fragment is meant as a "cms" fragment.  I want to pass some query data through to another backend after this resolves.

My query looks like this:

```
  query getFragmentsWithItems($keys: [String!]! 
                     $platform: PlatformType 
                     $version: String
                     $userInfo: UserInput
                     $userId: Int
                     ) {                     
    fragmentsWithItems(keys: $keys, platform: $platform, version: $version, userInfo: $userInfo, userId: $userId) {
      key
      data 
      children
      params
      items
    }
  }
```

Here's the problem: I have some query data in the `data` field from the Fragment.  That data is not available until that `Fragment` has resolved.  I want to take that data and send it to a different backend.  I want to do this with GraphQL, and I was hoping to do something like:

```
Fragment: () => {
  async query(obj, args, context, info, {modles}) => {
    const items = await models.getItems(obj.query_string);
  }
}
```

But I need the `user_info` and `user_id` that I passed to the original query.  Apparently that is only accessible from the `info` argument which is not meant to be used.

The other path I've taken is to have a manual resolver that does something like so:

```
const resolveFI = ({ keys, platform, version, userInfo, userId, models }) => {
  if (!keys || !keys.length) {
    return Promise.resolve(null);
  }
  return models.release.get({ platform, version }).then(release =>
    Promise.all(
      keys.map(key =>
        models.fragments.get({
          key,
          platform,
          version,
          release: release.id
        })
      )
    ).then(data => {
      const promises = [];
      data.rows.forEach(r => {
        if (r.data.query_data) {
          const d = {
            // Can just ignore
            filters: r.data.query_data.filters || {},
            user_info: userInfo,
            user_id: userId
          };
          promises.push(
            new Promise(resolve => {
              resolve(
                models.itemSearch.get(d).then(i => ({ items: i.items, ...r }))
              );
            })
          );
        }
        ...etc other backends
```

This works, however a manual promise chain seems to defeat the purpose of using GraphQL.

The last thing I tried was making `items` a non-scalar type, something like:

```
type Fragment {
items: ItemSearchResult(user_info: UserInput) etc
```

But since I can't pipe the actual result from Fragment to the ItemSearchResult that doesn't work.

I realize this is pretty long-winded so I'm open to edits or clarifying.
I'm looking to see if I've missed a better approach or if I should just bag it and have the client apps do the item query after they get the Fragment data back.

Comment: You said "I want to take that data and send it to a different backend" -- are you trying to resolve the `items` field by calling another API, or are you just trying to post part of your query results to another backend?

Comment: The second one.  I want to post what I get from querying for Fragments to an items backend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not that you're not supposed to use `info` -- it's just a tremendous pain in the butt to use ;) In all seriousness, it's meant to be used for optimization and more advanced use cases, so you shouldn't hesitate to use it if a better solution doesn't present itself. There are libraries out there ([like this one](https://www.npmjs.com/package/graphql-parse-fields)) that you can use to parse the object more easily.

That said, there's a couple of ways I imagine you could handle this:

1.) Inside your query resolver(s)

```
getFragmentsWithItems: async (obj, args, ctx, info) => {
  const fragments = await howeverYouDoThat()
  const backendCalls = fragments.map(fragment => {
    // extract whatever data you need from the fragment
    return asyncCallToBackEnd()
  })
  await backendCalls
  return fragments
}
```

Unfortunately, if you have a lot of different queries returning fragments, you'll end up with redundancy.

2.) Inside the resolver for an existing field (or an additional one) on the Fragment type.

If you go this route, and you need args passed to the query field, you *can* extract them using the info. Alternatively, you can also mutate the context object inside your query resolver and attach those arguments to it. Then, all resolvers "below" the query resolver (like the resolvers for your Fragment fields) can access those arguments through the context.

3.) Apollo Server lets you define a `formatResponse` function when configuring its middleware. This essentially provides a hook to do whatever you want with the response before it's returned to the client. You could parse the response inside that function and make the calls to the other backend from there.

Comment: Thanks for the comments and detail.  Since I'm not modifying `info` I suppose that would be the best workaround.  I hit enter too fast and I think [this package](https://github.com/lucasconstantino/graphql-resolvers) was what I was looking for the whole time.  It keeps the original arguments until one of the resolvers returns "undefined".